# how does TextMate do SVN and ftp?

Tags: svn, ftp, textmate, sftp

so far i only know to use Ctrl-Shift-A to do SVN in TextMate.  is there an easy way like Ctrl click on the file?  is ftp possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by using the FTP/SSH Textmate bundle: http://fuerstnet.de/ftpssh-bundle-textmate